# LINQ with conditions that some columns could be ignored depends on user input?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have `TableA` with 3 columns `ColA, ColB, ColC`. I'm developing a query function like the code shown below, because I want to make that if `ValueB` & `ValueC` are null, or `string.Empty`, then `ColB, ColC` may be not included in the query condition.....

```
IList<TableA> Query(object ValueA,string ValueB,string ValueC)
var result=(from TableA TA in entity.TableA
            where TA.ColA==ValueA
            &&(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ValueB)?1==1:TA.ColB==ValueB)
            &&(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ValueC)?1==1:TA.ColC==ValueC)
            select TA);
```

but I got a "System.NotSupportedException" exception while executed to this part:

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ValueB)
```

Could someone guide me a right way to make it?

Sorry for being a Taiwanese so the error message I met contains Chinese words.

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx PredicateBuilder may meet your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose your query conditionally.  Start with the base query:

```
var query = entity.TableA
    .Where(ta => ta.ColA == ValueA);
```

Then build upon the query when the other parameter values are not null or white space:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(ValueB))
{
    query = query.Where(ta => ta.ColB == ValueB);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace method. You can check like below

```
(ValueB == null || ValueB == "")
```